# Kettle api request in my Pentaho Server return 404

Tags: node.js, api, pentaho

I am usdin the pentaho server to make calls to the web service in **`localhost:8080/pentaho/home`**.

The fact is that when I want to make a request to activate a transform(ktr) that I have stored in that location the call service return error 404.

The simple example not working: **`localhost:8080/kettle/status/?xml=Y`** .

I make the call from nodejs to api rest as it puts in the pentaho documentation

```
function launchTrans(req, res) {
    let options = {
        url: `http://localhost:8080/kettle/status/?xml=Y`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
            'Cookie': globalString
        },
    };

    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.status(200).send(response);
        } else {
            console.log("There was an error " + error);
            res.status(500).send(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL should be `http://localhost:8080/pentaho/kettle/status/?xml=y` not `http://localhost:8080/kettle/status/?xml=y`. Your URL is not quite properly formatted. The format you're using is for the old PDI standalone server. In the new merged server where reporting and PDI is merged into one server you need to include the "pentaho" part of the URL.